# Asp.net MVC Xml Asynchronous Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

Is there any way to load and parse xml asynchronously  / parallely in asp.net mvc using .net 4.5 (not using jquery) ?

I need to load xml from 5-6 diff sources and then parse them combine results and then push to view.

Some examples show loadFromUriAsync in XmlDocument , but that function doesnt show in visual studio.

Comment: Usually you won't benefit from parallel CPU-bound processing in ASP.NET, unless your server workload is *really* low (i.e. there are very few concurrent requests from the clients). Check this for some more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22292403/1768303

Comment: Parsing XML is CPU-bound. You could load the content asynchronously from those sources and parse it into and XmlDocument or you could use a XmlReader which has a TAP asynchronous API.